# Sorting highest number in a linked list

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list

I am writing a program query that user for employee information such as a first name, last name, and a three digit employee id number. A struct and linked list are used to store the data. Traversing across the linked list occurs and the information of the employee with the highest id number is displayed.
  I am trying to define a pointer to the employee with the maximum ID so far, then go through the list in a loop and if the current ID is larger that the previous, replace the pointer.
  I have the idea in my head and the logic on paper, but I am very uncertain on how to form the process into code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct employee
{  char fname [21];
   char lname [21];
   int id;
   struct employee *next;
}DATA;

DATA* insertit (DATA *first, char firstn[], char lastn[], int idnum);

int main (void)
{
  DATA *head,
           *p;
  char firstname[21];
  char lastname[21];
  int idnumber,
             j,
             k,
             n;
  char ch,
       nl;

  head=NULL;
  for (j=0; j<21; j++)
    firstname[j]=' ';
  printf("Please enter the number of employees to enter information about:   ");
  scanf("%d", &n);

  for(k=0; k<n; k++)
    { printf("Please enter the employee's first name: \n");
      scanf("%s", firstname);
      printf("Please enter the employee's last name: \n");
      scanf("%s", lastname);
      printf("Please enter the employee's three digit id number: \n");
      scanf("%d", &idnumber);
      scanf("%c", &nl);
      head=insertit(head, firstname, lastname, idnumber);
      for (j=0; j<21; j++)
        firstname[j]= ' ';
   }
  p=head;
  while (p!=NULL)
  { printf("\n");
    printf("The employee's first name is: %s \n", p->fname);
    printf("The employee's last name is: %s \n", p->lname);
    printf("The employee's id number is: %d\n", p->id);
    p=p->next;
  }
printf("Hit any character to continue.");
scanf("%c", &ch);
}

DATA* insertit(DATA *first, char firstn[], char lastn[], int idnum)
/*Function to insert data into a linked list.*/

{
  DATA *p,
       *q,
    *newp;
  int found,
        len,
          i;
  found=0;
  q=first;
  p=first;

  while ((p!=NULL) && (!found))
  { if ((p->id < idnum) || (p-> id == idnum))
    { q=p;
      p=p->next;
    }
   else
     found=1;
  }
newp=(DATA *)malloc(sizeof(DATA));
newp->id=idnum;
strncpy(newp-> fname, firstn, 21);
strncpy(newp-> lname, lastn, 21);
newp->next=p;
if (q!=p)
  q->next=newp;
else
  first=newp;
return (first);
}
```

So, through my logic, I am thinking the following:

while (z=0; zsmall)
            {
    printf("The employee with the highest id number has the following first name: %s\n", p->fname);
    printf("The employee with the highest id number has the following last name: %s\n", p->lname);
    printf("The employee with the highest id number has the following id number: %d\n", p->id);
             }
       }

So, thanks to one user, I have the following code now:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct employee
{  char fname [21];
   char lname [21];
   int id;
   struct employee *next;
}DATA;

DATA* insertit (DATA *first, char firstn[], char lastn[], int idnum);
void printmax(DATA *head);

int main (void)
{
  DATA *head,
           *q,
           *p;
  char firstname[21];
  char lastname[21];
  int idnumber,
             j,
             k,
             n;
  char ch,
       nl;

  head=NULL;
  for (j=0; j<21; j++)
    firstname[j]=' ';
  printf("Please enter the number of employees that you would like to enter information about: ");
  scanf("%d", &n);

  for(k=0; k<n; k++)
    { printf("Please enter the employee's first name: \n");
      scanf("%s", firstname);
      printf("Please enter the employee's last name: \n");
      scanf("%s", lastname);
      printf("Please enter the employee's three digit id number: \n");
      scanf("%d", &idnumber);
      scanf("%c", &nl);
      head=insertit(head, firstname, lastname, idnumber);
      for (j=0; j<21; j++)
        firstname[j]= ' ';
   }
  p=head;
  while (p!=NULL)
  { printf("\n");
    printf("The employee's first name is: %s \n", p->fname);
    printf("The employee's last name is: %s \n", p->lname);
    printf("The employee's id number is: %d\n", p->id);
    p=p->next;
  }
  printf("Hit any character to continue."); scanf("%c", &ch);
}

DATA* insertit(DATA *first, char firstn[], char lastn[], int idnum)
/*Function to insert data into a linked list.*/
{
  DATA *p,
       *q,
    *newp;
  int found,
        len,
          i;
  found=0;
  q=first;
  p=first;

  while ((p!=NULL) && (!found))
  { if ((p->id < idnum) || (p-> id == idnum))
    { q=p;
      p=p->next;
    }
   else
 found=1;
  }
newp=(DATA *)malloc(sizeof(DATA));
newp->id=idnum;
strncpy(newp-> fname, firstn, 21);
strncpy(newp-> lname, lastn, 21);
newp->next=p;
if (q!=p)
  q->next=newp;
else
  first=newp;
return (first);
}

void printmax (DATA *head)
{
  DATA *highest = head;
  DATA *next = head.next;
  while (next != NULL) 
     {
      if (next->highid > highest->highid) {
      highest = next;
      }
    next = next->next;
  }
  printf("The employee with the highest id number has the first name: %s\n",highest->fname);
  printf("The employee with the highest id number has the last name: %s\n",highest->lname);
  printf("The employee with the highest id number has the id number: %d\n", highest->id);
 }
}
```

I have hand-traced the program and it seemed to work fine, but when I compile it, the following errors occur:

- error: request for member ‘next’ in something not a structure or union
  DATA *next = head.next;
- error: ‘DATA’ has no member named ‘highid’
   if (next->highid > highest->highid) {
- error: ‘DATA’ has no member named ‘highid’
   if (next->highid > highest->highid) {

I am not familiar with these error messages, so I researched them in an effort to determine their cause, however, I am still uncertain. Thus, I would greatly appreciate it if someone would explain the cause and possibly a solution. I would like to thank you all very much for your help so far.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Write some code implementing the logic you have and then come back, show us, and ask about something you're having trouble with.

Comment: `strncpy(newp-> fname, firstn, 21);` is a problem if `strelen(firstn) >= 21`.

Comment: I ask if someone would please explain the sorting method in respect to this example and explain a way in which it can be employed. I am not looking for a straight 'here is the code answer' because I would love to thoroughly understand the process and how it falls into the code, but I am looking for help in sorting in respect to this example. Thank you for your interest! @chux

Comment: Review `qsort()`.  It takes as a parameter, a compare function, allowing all sort of sorting criteria.

Comment: `for (j=0; j<21; j++) firstname[j]= ' ';` : this isn't required. It a problem that is not terminated with NUL if scanf fails to read.

Comment: Your update implies finding a maximum.  This is simply a singe pass through the array.  Sorting the array implies putting all array elements in some order.  Your code looks good for a starting point for finding the maximum.

Comment: I have correctly sorted and printed out the employee information (the first name, last name and the id number). I am now trying to find a way to print out the information of the employee with the highest id number. So, would I declare the pointer *highid, the int z and the int small in main? Also, would I use the pointer p to point the first name, the last name and the id number in order to print out the information of the employee with the highest id number? I am not certain about what you mean by a single pass through the array. I would appreciate it if you explain that a bit. @chux

Comment: Messages like `error: request for member ‘next’ in something not a structure or union DATA *next = head.next;` mean you used a `.` instead of a `->` or you used `->` instead of a `.`.  In this case, `head` is a pointer, so you need the arrow operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the highest employee and and to print it.

```
void PritMax(const DATA *head) {
  const DATA *highest = head;
  const DATA *next = head->next;
  while (next != NULL) {
    if (next->id > highest->id) {
      highest = next;
    }
    next = next->next;
  }
  printf("The employee with the highest id number has the first name: %s\n",
      highest->fname);
  printf("The employee with the highest id number has the last name: %s\n",
      highest->lname);
  printf("The employee with the highest id number has the id number: %d\n",
      highest->id);
}
```

Comment: First of all, thank you so much madam or sir! When I traced through it by hand, everything appeared well and good, however, the compiler is giving me errors that I have never seen before. I did research them, but still do not understand. My errors read: request for member ‘next’ in something not a structure or union DATA *next = head.next; ‘DATA’ has no member named ‘highid’ if (next->highid > highest->highid) ‘DATA’ has no member named ‘highid’ if (next->highid > highest->highid) @chux

Comment: `const DATA *next = head.next;` --> `const DATA *next = head->next;`   `if (next->highid > highest->highid)` --> `if (next->id > highest->id)`

Comment: Thank you so very much madam or sir! I appreciate all of your help! You were very informative, and skillful and I understand the code very well. (: @chux

Comment: BTW: Use width limits on `scanf("%s", ....` such as `scanf("%20s", firstname); scanf("%20s", lastname);`

Comment: I have never thought of that! That is so smart. Thank you! (: @chux

Comment: **Warning:** the code will work only on non-empty list.